# JS : is there any way to focus on somewhere else except on the web page?

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I want to focus on somewhere else except on the page shown, such as focusing on address bar, new tab or so forth.

I need to fix a certain problem, and tried to use blur() first, but it seems not working..

Comment: *I need to fix a certain problem* - you should detail *that* problem instead. Because it's more likely to have a fix. You won't be able to do what you're asking via Javascript

Comment: @CodingIntrigue ok, on my web, it seems like focusing on the body, but not showing any focussed mark when trying on Chrome. And it then works fine when I give focus on address bar or somewhere else and come back. That was why I wanted just to give focus on the address bar with onload event.

Comment: You should put that into a question along with the code you tried to use `blur()` with - people will better be able to provide a solution with that